# Prstat -t alternate command for linux

Tags: bash, shell

What is a similar command in Linux for the command from Solaris:

```
prstat -t
```

I am interested to get user vice resource consumption (i.e. memory and processor).

It should give output as:

```
NPROC UserName SWAP RSS Memory TimeCPU
```

Is there any scripts or tool available to generate more or less similar output?

Answer (score 0):

ps command might be what you need, try this : `ps aux`

It will print the following columns/info :

> USER        PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME
>   COMMAND

Comment: it is returning output on the basis of processes, but i need users wise. Anyways thanks!.